# Horizontal align of many Buttons in UL in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have created a list of buttons using `ul` as given below in the code,

```css
#div_buttons ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

#div_buttons ul input {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="div_buttons">
  <ul>
    <li><input type="button" ID="button_1" value="Button 1" /></li><br />
    <li><input type="button" ID="button_2" value="Button 2" /></li><br />
    <li><input type="button" ID="button_3" value="Button 3" /></li><br />
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here i want to arrange them and display the buttons as horizontal list instead of vertical..how can i do that? Actually i want to do this in ASP.NET `<asp:Button>` instead of `<input type="submit">` but since the snippet here doesn't support ASP.NET i displayed in `HTML`. Im not sure what CSS to add to arrange the UL in horizontal way.

Comment: `<asp:Button>` actually renders as `<input type="submit">`, so your css should reference the input tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer given above is perfectly right.But it uses CSS.

I found a simple solution to your answer that little bit different and also inconvenient. But i am writing just for your knowledge purpose.

If you know word named

```
 nbsp;
```

that is used for spacing between two tags. So you can use one li tag and make 3 button inside it(1 li tag only). But use & before nbsp; between two input tags.

```
<li>
      <input type="button" ID="button_1" value="Button 1" /> &nbsp; 
      <input type="button" ID="button_2" value="Button 2" /> &nbsp; 
      <input type="button" ID="button_3" value="Button 3" /> &nbsp; 
</li>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `display: inline` (*`float:left` will also work*) on you `li` elements to display them horizontally:

```
#div_buttons li {
  display: inline;
}
```

Example:

```css
#div_buttons ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

#div_buttons ul input {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#div_buttons li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="div_buttons">
  <ul>
    <li><input type="button" ID="button_1" value="Button 1" /></li>
    <li><input type="button" ID="button_2" value="Button 2" /></li>
    <li><input type="button" ID="button_3" value="Button 3" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

In an ASP.NET web form the code for the `.aspx` file would look something like:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="div_buttons">
      <ul>
        <li><asp:Button runat="server" Text="Button 1" ID="Button_1" /></li>
        <li><asp:Button runat="server" Text="Button 2" ID="Button_2" /></li>
        <li><asp:Button runat="server" Text="Button 3" ID="Button_3" /></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: i tried but it wont work..maybe is it because im using `<asp:Button>`? please give me a solution for ASP.NET button..

Comment: @ManoPrathibhanC In ASP.NET `<asp:Button>` will render as `<input type"submit" ... />`. I ran this in VS and it still worked, mine showing you you are using `<asp:Button>`? I've gave the `<asp:Button>`'s I used in my environment in an edit above.